# How to edit key/value pairs in multidimensional, associative arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I hope my title makes sense, I'm no quite sure how to describe my problem in a shot way, so here is the long version:

I'm working in PHP and I have 2 MySQL tables that are displaying items and their specs (I cannot change the table structure).

T1 (Items)

```
+---------+--------+
| itemID  |  item  |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | TV     |
|       2 | Radio  |
|       3 | Camera |
|     ... | ...    | 
+---------+--------+
```

T2 (Specs)

```
+---------+--------+------+
| itemID  | specID | spec |
+---------+--------+------+
|       1 | color  | red  |
|       1 | weight | 10   |
|       1 | price  | 499  |
|       2 | color  | blue |
|     ... | ...    | ...  |
+---------+--------+------+
```

I want a multidimensional, associative array like this

```
array(
[0]=> array(
    "itemID"=>"1",
    "item"=>"TV", 
    "color"=>"red",
    "weight"=>"10", 
    "price"=>"499") 
[1]=> array(
    "itemID"=>"2", 
    "item"=>"Radio", 
    "color"=>"blue",
    ...)
    )
```

It seems impossible to me to achieve that with only one query.
I try to query the two tables separately, rearrange the `key=>value` in T2 and use `array_merge`.

What I have so far is the array from T1

```
array(
    [0]=> array( 
        "itemID"=> "1",
        "item"=>"TV")
    [1]=> array(
        "itemID"=> "2",
        "item"=>"Radio")
    [2]=> array(
        "itemID"=> "3",
        "item"=>"Camera")
    ...)
```

From T2 the array comes in the same form

```
array(
    [0]=> array( 
        "itemID"=> "1",
        "specID"=> "color",
        "spec"=>"red")
    [1]=> array(
        "itemID"=> "1",
        "specID"=> "weight",
        "spec"=>"10")
    [2]=> array(
        "itemID"=> "1",
        "specID"=> "price",
        "spec"=>"499")
    ...)
```

After changing the array I will get a single numeric array, not two associative arrays like I want

```
array(
    [0]=> array(
        [0] => ["itemID" => "1","color" => "red","weight" => "10", "price" => "499"])
    [1]=> array(
        [0] => ["itemID" => "2","color" => "blue",...])
    ...)
```

My code is

```
$newArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<=n; $i++) {
    foreach($oldArray[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'itemID') {
            $a = $key . '" => "' . $value . '",';
            }
        elseif($key === 'specID') {
            $b = '"' . $key . '" => "';
            }
        elseif($key === 'spec') {
            $c = $value;
            }
    }
    $newArray[] = [$a.$b.$c];
}
```

Maybe I'm completely wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Seems like what you need is a JOIN in SQL. Try to join your two tables based on itemID.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: JOIN is good only if the number of specs per item is constant. If it varies, or if `specID` can vary, it is not convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This table structure is great if the number of item parameters is variable.

The simplest approach is the following:

```
$array1 = array(...); // from table 1
$array2 = array(...); // from table 2
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 AS $v) {
    $result[ $v['itemID'] ] = $v;
}
foreach ($array2 AS $v) {
    $result[ $v['itemID'] ][ $v['specId'] ] = $v['spec'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

This will fetch everything you need in 1 query:

```
select items.itemID,
group_concat(concat(specs.specID,":",specs.spec)) as properties
from items join specs on items.itemID=specs.itemID
group by items.itemID;
```

Results will look like this:

```
+--------+-------------------------------+
| itemID | properties                    |
+--------+-------------------------------+
|      1 | color:red,weight:10,price:499 |
|      2 | color:blue                    |
+--------+-------------------------------+
```

I'll leave it to you to populate the array but it should be trivial using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) first with "," delimiter then with ":"